# use click to amend rendered page

Tags: jquery, confluence

I'm having trouble with a certain jquery in Confluence.
I have this code:

```
## @param pmname:title=Name(select)|required=true|type=string

<script> 
AJS.toInit(function() {

$(".sectionMacroWithBorder").not(":contains('$parampmname')").addClass("hidden");

});

</script>
```

Which works just perfect - hides all sections not containing given text.
However, when I try to create a button to activate the same code on click

```
 ## @param pmname:title=Name(select)|required=true|type=string

 <script>
 AJS.toInit(function() {

 $('.wiki-content').append('<button id="addnew" type="button">$parampmname</button> ');

 $('addnew').on('click', 'button', function() {

 $(".sectionMacroWithBorder").not(":contains('$parampmname')").addClass("hidden");
  }); 

 });

 </script>
```

The jquery creates the button at the bottom of the page okay, but nothing happens on click with the same variable given as in the first example. I also tried `.addnew` and `#addnew` for the `.on .`

Here's a fiddle (thanks Mark Schultheiss!) with similar buttons working: http://jsfiddle.net/Cecfu/1/

Am I doing something wrong or is it a Confluence jquery pecularity?

Answer (score 0):

this :

```
$('addnew').on('click', 'button', function() { ...
```

should be :

```
$('#addnew').on('click', function() { ....
```

because `button` has `id="addnew"` and is not a child of `#addnew`

Or you could eventually do if you prefer :

```
$('.wiki-content').on('click', '#addnew', function() { ...
```

... to delegate the `click` event to present or future child elements with `id="addnew"`

Comment: Yeah, I played with that before posting. It doesn't work, unfortunately, though it should. Does that work for you in Confluence or is that just how it should be?

Comment: @EasyLife : it's the way `.on()` should work regardless the platform http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

try #addnew for the click listener

```
AJS.toInit(function() {

$('.wiki-content').append('<button id="addnew" type="button">$parampmname</button> ');

$('#addnew').on('click', 'button', function() {

$(".sectionMacroWithBorder").not(":contains('$parampmname')").addClass("hidden");
 }); 

});
```

Comment: Already did that and even mentioned in the initial question. Doesn't work in Confluence...